# CSS codes does not work at the same time

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I have this css code which gives a picture an opacity, see code below:

**CSS1:**

> .hover:hover { opacity:0.8;}

**HTML1:**

```
<a href="http://www.byggprojektoren.se"> 
<img class="hover" src="http://byggprojektoren.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/HomepagePic.jpg"/> 
</a>
```

But the CSS above collides with the following code:

**CSS2:**

```
.medarbetare-img {
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 16px;
```

**HTML2:**

```
<div class="medarbetare-img" style="background:url(http://byggprojektoren.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/R2.jpg) center top no-repeat;">
                    </div>
```

When I remove the CSS2 the CSS1 works fine. But when both are there, the CSS1 gets overwritten somehow. Does anyone have an idea on how to rewrite the both CSS for them both to work?

Comment: How are you including the CSS?

Comment: What do you mean? I am using a css plugin for wordpress if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably CCS2 override CSS1 because you are adding it after CSS1 in your HTML code. If you want to avoid overriding, merge them in one CSS file and be sure that your selectors are unique, in opposite, you will have overriding again

Comment: Hi Sasa, I just changed positions to them and it works fine now. Thank you for your solution. Btw they are on the same css :)